# Rails + Ajax - update view based on combo-box choice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Just a heads-up, I'm a total beginner as far as ajax is concerned and am just trying to find my way around it, so please bear with me :)

I have a View with a combo box in it (generated through a collection_select) and I display some data on the side of that form that essentially gives more details about the user's choice.

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to change that description on the side as soon as the customer makes a different selection in the combo. Basically, figure out what the current choice is, request data from the model, display returned data on the screen.

What's the simplest / most elegant way of achieving that? I think understanding the process would be a good launching ramp into the rest of the async View world for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ajax is necessary in this situation. Simply preload all the description values and store them in hidden divs:

```
<div class="description" id="choice1">
   description for choice1 ...
</div>

 ...
```

Then hide them all:

```
// somewhere in your stylesheet
div.description {
  display: none;
}
```

And finally on client side, bind to wanted events of the combo box:

```
   // checkout documentation for other events, like select 
   $('some_id').change(function(data){
     $('div.description').css('display', 'none');

     var id = // get information about selected choice and figure out the id of description
     $('div.description#' + id).css('display', 'block');
   });
```

Chekout documentation for exact details but the main idea should be clear. In this way, you'll save yourself some unnecessary requests to your server.